# Android: Changing entry point activity to app messes up app update

Tags: android

This is the second time this has happened to me now. I changed the starting activity of my app, and put out an update, and now the icon on people's phone will not open my app. The only way they can open it is through the downloads section of their Android Market app, or if they uninstall and reinstall the app, causing them to lose ALL their data.

I have no problem with updates on my N1, but every other Android phone has a problem with this. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only way they can open it is
>   through the downloads section of their
>   Android Market app, or if they
>   uninstall and reinstall the app,
>   causing them to lose ALL their data.

Powering their phone off and on should work as well.

> I have no problem with updates on my
>   N1, but every other Android phone has
>   a problem with this. Why?

It's a question of when the home screen app elects to reload its launcher data. Different home screen implementations handle this differently. You will have the same problem with any user-created shortcuts and the like.

Comment: Thanks. I had a user email me and tell me that powering off their phone solves the problem, so this seems to be the best solution. It's also good to know why this is happening, which I know now. Again, thanks!